# Нужно поднять сервер на Windows

Tags: веб-сервер, iis

Предо мной стоит задача - поднять веб-сервер на базе Windows 2008 standart.

**Что мне нужно?**

Организовать "место для сайта" на выбранном сервере. Для успешной работы сайта необходимы следующие технологии: PHP 7+, MySQL, возможность запланированного запуска скриптов, модуль отправки почты.

Как это реализовать ну совсем не понимаю, абсолютная каша в голове. Просто брожу по интернету на протяжении нескольких часов и читаю статьи о том, как поднять веб-сервер. Такие поиски привели меня к IIS. Поставить его конечно не составило труда, но теперь стоит вопрос как в "это" запихнуть php 7.1.16 к примеру. Для версии 5.хх есть инсталяторы, для 7.хх не нашел. Как поднять MySQL, будет ли там планировщик задач.

Возможно в своих поисках я пришел к неверному решению и есть более простой способ на данной машине развернуть веб-сервер? 
Если можете подсказать где почерпнуть знания по данной теме - подскажите.
Если можете дать совет по данной ситуации - буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php для 2008 тоже должно работать, разве что шаги установки IIS могут незначительно отличаться. MySQL просто устанавливаете инсталятором для Win и настраиваете под ваши задачи.

Comment: А почему обязательно на винде? Да ещё и на такой старой?

Comment: Требования заказчика, я бы с великим удовольствием бы начал бы знакомство с серверным администрированием с поднятием сервера на Ubuntu, но мне досталось это и к сожалению с ним я должен работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инструкция по уставновке от php первого пользователя была немного размыта поэтому я продолжил поиски и наткнулся на следующее решение.

Скачиваем php с офф. сайта и распаковываем. Прописываем в PATH два пути: до самой папки с php, и до вложенной в нее папки ext (в моем случае "**C:\php;C:\php\ext**").

В меню управление IIS в разделе "*Handler Mappings*" жмем "*Add Module Mapping...*" и прописываем все как на скриншоте ниже.

[image: Add Module Mapping specific]

Возвращаемся обратно в меню управления IIS и заходим в "*Default Document*", где добавляем новое значение '**index.php**' и поднимаем его на самый верх.

С помощью данных манипуляций я смог установить PHP 7.1.16 на своей север. Данный пост не инструкция, это просто описание того, как я решил проблему с которой столкнулся.